# Is validation a necessary step before verification?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am in the process of reviewing all my codes and I have second thoughts about the necessity of validating a user input before verifying it. Take for example, the verification of a credit card CVV:

```
// validation required?
if(!preg_match('/^[\d]{3,4}$/', $_POST['card_CVV']))
{
 unset($_POST['card_CVV']);
 $error++;

// verification
}
elseif($card_CVV != $_POST['card_CVV'])
{
 $error++;
}

// pass verification
else
{
 // process transaction
}
```

Should verification be carried out without validation?

Comment: Well I guess even here there's injection possible. EVER and ALWAYS validate AND filter user input - means you shouldn't use the unfiltered `$_POST` variable in the elseif anyway, right ?!

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the difference between verification and validation. They seem like virtually the same thing...you are checking to see if the input is in the expected form, usually in a fairly simplistic way, usually to get an error message back to the user, before more demanding processing of those inputs.

Comment: @ Dan Surfrider, I am not storing the user data, would that still post a risk?

Comment: @cdeszaq: So can I say that it is an unnecessary step if I am not going to send an error message back to the user?

Comment: @DanSurfrider Not sure I agree with your final question.  A Bad person can't fiddle your $_POST[] once it's in your script.  You can refer the $_POST[] as often as you want, as long as you clean it before use.  $_POST[] vars are not inherently bad, they will just contain untrusted data.  It won't magically hack your `if`  (It *is* best to clean up the POST var as soon as you can and then not touch it, but that's so you don't "forget")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case it is not necessary and in fact does nothing because presumably if it was in the wrong format it would never be correct.

Where it would make more sense is to validate the format on the client side in javascript before the form is submitted, maybe as they type if you want to get more fancy, that way the user gets immediate feedback and knows that it's wrong before submitting.

Also you should be aware of injection possibilities if you the content of `$_POST['card_CVV']` is ever put into a SQL query or displayed somewhere as html.  You say that you don't store it so and from the code shown it is only used for direct string comparison so I suspect it should be fine, but be please be mindful of this in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Realy depends on the context and/or error messages you need to display back to the user .

For example you need the above validation on the first input, and if it's not a valid input display the message to the user. However if you whant to check if the user entered the correct card_CVV you need both becouse youre error message is different: not a valid cvv or cvv does not match .

Comment: Can I say that if I just want to give out a general message "This transaction has been declined.", then I wouldn't need the validation step?

Comment: yes, but that whont help the user at all, if you're a developer you need to concider making clear and meaningfull errors to the users input actions .

Comment: Yes, I would usually give more precise error message, but for a credit card transaction, would it be too much of a hint?

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, you need to make sure your processing code behaves correctly, which almost always means you have to fail the processing if you don't have the inputs you need. It doesn't really matter where in your processing pipeline you check for things, but it is a good practice to "fail fast" and let users know what is happening.

At the same time, you don't want to repeat code (keep things DRY), which means that you should not be checking for the same issues more than once.